# Displaying duplicates and non-duplicates data from column in database - laravel

Tags: php, laravel

In my database, i have a list of responses collected from customers that i want to gather and generate a pie chart for. (like that of google forms).

In my database, i have responses that are the same and other not like below

```
Client 1   Client 2    Client
  Yes        Yes         No
```

So in the column above, i have `Yes(2) and No(1)`.  I want to gather, count and display my query response like below

```
Yes : 2  , No: 1
```

But with my code below

```
 public function answers_chart(Survey $survey)
   {
         $response = DB::select( DB::raw(" select * from (
          SELECT questionnaire_id, COUNT(answer) as e_count
          FROM Answer
          GROUP BY answer
          )a where  a.e_count > 1)); 
   }
```

I get the response like below, meaning it is only counting the `Yes`

```
[{"e_count":2}]
```

How can i achieve something like this?

**Table**

public function up()

```
 {
        Schema::create('Answer', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');         
            $table->integer('question_id');
            $table->integer('questionnaire_id');
            $table->string('answer');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Comment: add the table's schema in the question.

Comment: @DsRaj, i have added the schema

Answer (score 1):

You have a.e_count > 1. This means that the GROUP BY answer has only 1 'No' in it and you only want the ones that has more than 1 of 'No' or 'Yes'. You should remove `a where  a.e_count > 1)`.

I highly discourage doing queries like this though. Laravel has a powerful built in Eloquent ORM. Take a look at it [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent) for better use of the Laravel framework!

Comment: Advocate of the devil: I highly encourage doing queries like this. It makes your code framework independent and probably faster since you don't need to load an entire ORM for a relatively easy select.

Comment: If this is the only table in the database I would have to agree, but using this schema for bigger projects makes it inconvenient in the long term. I do not know the size of Switz' project though.

Comment: That's taste I think. Very valid point but it doesn't weigh up to my need of being independent from frameworks :)

Answer (score 0):

may be using case statments will be better, for example

```
SELECT
COUNT(CASE WHEN answer = '1' THEN 1 END) AS yes,
COUNT(CASE WHEN answer= '0' THEN 1 END) AS no
FROM ANSWER
```

Comment: How would this query stand if the response are not Yes or No response?  I added the Yes or No as an example of responses that could be the same

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Model::select(DB::raw("COUNT(CASE WHEN answer = 'Yes' THEN 1 END) AS e_count"))->first(); // Eloquent approach

DB::table('answer')->select(DB::raw("COUNT(CASE WHEN answer = 'Yes' THEN 1 END) AS e_count"))->first(); // Query Builder approach
```

Comment: You can add the count of the 'no' answer by own so you will get better idea